# Trouble with a lottery contract

Tags: solidity, remix

The task was to make lottery smart contract where:

- Entry fee: 25000000000000000
- Duration: Every 10 Minutes
- 50% Winners and 50% Losers
- Winner Gets 1.8X
- Losers gets 0X

I have come up with the following code

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.5.0<0.9.0;
contract Lottery{
address public Lottery_master;
address [] public participants;
mapping (address => uint) public winner;
uint [] public winners;

constructor(){
Lottery_master= (msg.sender);
}
function reset_Lottery() private{
participants= new address[](0);
}
 modifier adminOnly() {
 require(Lottery_master == msg.sender, "You are not the owner");
        _;
 }
receive () external payable{
 require(msg.value==25000000000000000 wei);
 require(msg.sender!=Lottery_master);
    participants.push((msg.sender));
}
function random() public view returns(uint){
 return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked( block.difficulty,block.timestamp,participants.length)));
}
function find(uint index) public view returns(bool){
 for(uint c=0; c<=winners.length;c++){
 if (winners[c]==winners[index]){
 return true;
 }
 }
 return false;
}
function pick_winner() public adminOnly {
 require(participants.length>0);
 uint l= participants.length;
 uint c;
 while(c<=participants.length/2){
 uint winning_index= random()%l;
 if(!find(winning_index)){
    winners.push(winning_index);
    c++;
    winner[participants[winning_index]]=c;
 }
 

}
}
function claim() public{
 require(winner[msg.sender]!=0);
 payable(msg.sender).transfer(45000000000000000 wei);

}
}
```

**The problem:**
I am able to enter partcipants into the lottery, but I am not able to run the pick winner function or the payout function and am getting the folllowing error

```sh
[![
 
transact to Lottery.pick_winner pending ... 
 
[vm]from: 0x617...5E7f2to: Lottery.pick_winner() 0x5c4...165CFvalue: 0 weidata: 0x87a...4beb0logs: 0hash: 0x2e0...31e9b
status  false Transaction mined but execution failed
transaction hash    0x2e07117b73a303d2c3d591f7b142cd918478f28953976adca747c976a9d31e9b
from    0x617F2E2fD72FD9D5503197092aC168c91465E7f2
to  Lottery.pick_winner() 0x5c4B3fC5B79c6cfeD886bc8BD0b6Fd72DA4165CF
gas 80000000 gas
transaction cost    25524 gas 
execution cost  25524 gas 
hash    0x2e07117b73a303d2c3d591f7b142cd918478f28953976adca747c976a9d31e9b
input   0x87a...4beb0
decoded input   {}
decoded output  {}
logs    []
val 0 wei
 
transact to Lottery.pick_winner errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
>
][1]][1]
```

Any help to correct my code will be greatly appreciated.
Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

The code has several issues:

1. Having proper indentation, the code unnecessarily hard to read and understand
2. Out of bound access.

```
function find(uint index) public view returns (bool) {
   for(uint c = 0; c <= winners.length; c++) {
       if (winners[c] == winners[index]) {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Accessing an array by an invalid index causes the whole transaction to revert. The valid positions for `winners` are `0`, ..., `winners.length-1`, it is a zero based array.

`index` is never tested for a valid array position. Moreover it is comparing `winners[c]` agains `winners[index]`, and it makes no sense. It is likely you wanted to compare agains `index` because `winners` contains indices to participants.

```
function find(uint index) public view returns (bool) {
   for(uint c = 0; c < winners.length; c++) {
       if (winners[c] == index) {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```